# Positive Integral Solutions to Matrix Equation

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Given a matrix, $M$, and a vector ${b}$, with positive integral entries, how many solutions are there to the equation

$$Mx = b$$

where $x$ is a positive integral vector? Any solution or reference to a problem like this to be solved would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that both $M$ and $b$ have integers only?

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the knapsack problem which is #$P$-hard, meaning that it is very very difficult (no fast algorithm) to compute the exact number of solutions. If the dimension of $x$ is fixed then you can use the software LattE https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software.php to compute the number of integer points in the feasible region in polynomial time. (This is the same as the answer to your problem)

Comment: I'm not sure it is the knapsack problem as that deals with maximizing a linear equation subject to some constraints. I am interested in just the number of solutions.

Comment: @Mastrel "Knapsack" can be either exact (you have to fill the knapsack exactly) or maximized (fill as much as possible and maximize the value). I am talking about exact knapsack where all you care about is filling the knapsack exactly using either 0/1 or non-negative integer of each item (depending on which version you want) and there are no cost values for items. This is still a #$P$-hard problem.

Comment: I may be missing something, but to me, a knapsack problem has to involve maximizing something, and not how many ways you can maximize it, whereas my question is how many ways can get a solution, which may not be a maximum solution.

Comment: @Mastrel just maximize the zero function to see the equivalence. Then all feasible solutions are optimal solutions so counting optimal solutions is the same as counting feasible solutions.

Comment: But the knapsack problem doesn't count solutions.

Comment: I said it was #$P$-hard to count solutions by equivalence to the knapsack problem variant of counting solutions to knapsack. I didn't say that the original knapsack problem is counting solutions. I was talking about counting solutions for the knapsack problem, which is a different problem than original knapsack, and harder.